# Justify list items in nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML for my menu

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

This is the HTML as Bootstrap suggests u use so the menu wil be responsive when resizing. Currently it looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p1mw2cjc/1/)

The problem is that i want the `<li>` items to justify depending on the width.
Bootstrap has `.nav-justified` for this but when I do that is doesn't show properly and it floats all the `<li>` items to the left.
That looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p1mw2cjc/2/)

How can I make the menu items justify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `navbar-nav` class on the `ul.nav` element with `nav-pills` (or `nav-tabs`).

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <!-- etc. -->
</ul>
```

See: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

Comment: That doesn't justify the `<li>` elements, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p1mw2cjc/3/)

Comment: You removed the `nav-justified` class, look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p1mw2cjc/4/) . Isn't this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Yep i had this problem before, all you have to do is change the % width of the class, you have to specify the width as the default has the width at 1%

```
.nav-justified>li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 15%;
}
```

Comment: That's not justifying, thats just setting the width of the items.